# Whats the best way to create a HTML sitemap for a website with over 40,000 pages?

Tags: php, html, seo, sitemap

I have already got a XML sitemap of the pages, but wanting a HTML version for the users to browse through (and also good for SEO i guess, making sure that every page will be link to).

My PHP website has a page for every village / town / county / region in the UK and Ireland, so im guessing that one page with every link in a list wouldn't be the best approach.

Should i...

- a) Have a list of all the counties then a sub HTML sitemap page for each listing all the towns and villages alphabetically?
- b) Same as option 'a' but with an a-z bar along the top, then a separate page for each county and letter with a list of the towns and villages?
- c) Something else??

Any suggestions for this solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Non-programming related questions about your website are off topic at StackOverflow.  Questions about your website should be asked at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/   This particular question is open ended and asking for opinions, so it should be closed rather than moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As google suggests more and more for the websites to have user-friendly pages, I suppose the sitemaps should follow the same logic.

If you have structured your data following this  village / town / state / country / continent,
I would simply have my sitemaps follow this same structure.

The first reason is that it would be the easiest to implement in my opinion, and it's the best hierarchy you could find. Villages should be sorted by alphabetical name or zipcode (depending if the country has some or not)

Comment: Good advice :). Im thinking that my option 'b' would be the best solution as the user would know what county/state their looking for, then just click on the letter and find the village name. As ive already got a series of linked select fields on the homepage to narrow their search.

Comment: Make sure you cache the sitemap so someone can not slowdown (or even worse) your website by hitting F5 a couple of times.

Comment: Will do @Mike , i know of this url http://php.dzone.com/news/php-caching-pages-with-output- for info on caching... any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, speaking only about sitemaps, they should be made as files and not computed on demand for your case I believe. If you already have your database, and if the website urls don't change, you don't need to update it.
Simply generate the sitemaps files once, and if you change something simply regenerate it?